# Simple slope estimates differ between emmeans package and interactions package?

Tags: r

I computed simple slopes for an interaction with the `sim_slopes()` function from the *interactions* package and using the `emtrends()` function from the *emmeans* package and results (both the estimates and standard errors) seem to slightly differ even though both computations are based on the same linear model (using the lm() function). Is there an explanation for this? I've pasted the code and output below. x is a continuous variable and z is a categorical variable with 3 levels.

```
model1 <- lm(DV ~ z * x, data = data)

>   sim_slopes(model1, pred = x, modx = z, johnson_neyman = FALSE)
SIMPLE SLOPES ANALYSIS 

Slope of x when z = 3: 

  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------ ------ -------- ------
  0.50   0.10     4.89   0.00

Slope of x when z = 2: 

  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------ ------ -------- ------
  0.74   0.09     7.83   0.00

Slope of x when z = 1: 

  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------ ------ -------- ------
  0.33   0.10     3.37   0.00

>   emtrends(model1, ~ z, var="x")
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 z               x.trend  SE    df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 1                0.290 0.0669 1016    0.158    0.421
 2                0.618 0.0611 1016    0.498    0.738
 3                0.411 0.0612 1016    0.291    0.531
```

Comment: good question, but it would be great to have a [mcve] too ...  Could we see `summary(model1)` please ?

Comment: The NOTE message before the output suggests that there is at least one other factor in play that interacts with the others, and that that factor is being averaged over. There are different sorts of weights that can be used in such averaging. It is also questionable to compute average slopes in the presence of such interactions (hence the warning message). I believe the presence of other factor(s) and how they are handled probably accounts for the discrepancies seen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to reproduce your results.
I tried interactions between `z` and `x` by using `iris` data, where

```
DV <- iris$Sepal.Length  
z  <- iris$Species     # z is a categorical variable with 3 levels : setosa, virginica, and versicolor
x  <- iris$Petal.Length #x is a continuous variable.
```

The resulted slope estimates and corresponding standard errors in `sim_slopes` and `emtrends` are almost identical.

```
model1 <- lm(DV ~ z * x, data = iris)
sim_slopes(model1, pred = x, modx = z, johnson_neyman = FALSE)
#SIMPLE SLOPES ANALYSIS 

#Slope of x when z = virginica: 

#  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
#------ ------ -------- ------
# 1.00   0.09    11.43   0.00

# Slope of x when z = versicolor: 

#  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
#------ ------ -------- ------
#  0.83   0.10     8.10   0.00

# Slope of x when z = setosa: 

#  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
# ------ ------ -------- ------
#  0.54   0.28     1.96   0.05

emtrends(model1, ~ z, var="x")
# z          x.trend     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
# setosa       0.542 0.2768 144 -0.00476     1.09
# versicolor   0.828 0.1023 144  0.62611     1.03
# virginica    0.996 0.0871 144  0.82360     1.17

# Confidence level used: 0.95
```

However, this warning message: `NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions` does not emerge in my trial.

This result indicates that both packages use the same method to compute the slope. Due to the warning message that emerged in your result, I would suggest you to check again your `z` and `x` data and to reconsider how sensible the interaction of these variables is.

My suggestion is based on the explanation of the `emmeans` author here:
https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-03-30/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html